# how to debug Ubuntu start-up with BusyBox

Tags: boot, grub2, busybox

Instead of the usual start-up I'm seeing a screen with GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3 and the following options:
Ubuntu, 
Advanced options for Ubuntu, 
Memory test (memtest86+), 
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Selecting Ubuntu (or other options, such as recovery mode via advanced options) show me this:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs)
```

I'm not running a partition with Windows (which other sources suggest is more common with this problem), however my computer did not shut down properly last time. Any help/ideas on a fix would be much appreciated!

Comment: See:[Repair Linux boot failures in GRUB 2 rescue mode](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/)

Comment: Please post the output before the error message.